# SwiftUI view layouts with frame maxHeight and .infinity

Tags: layout, frame, swiftui

How to layout views in SwiftUI in such way

1. I have input fields that I want to stretch to fill available space
2. This inputs are placed in **VStack** in such way that I am giving them `frame(height: 40)`
3. This **VStack** is inside white box which has `frame(maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.8)`

And the last white box is not adjusting to number of inputs in for  **VStack** but rather takes **0.8 space** and then this inputs are spread inside **VStack** instead (more spacing than needed is added.

I do not understand why such thing is happening.

```
FormView()
     .frame(
       maxWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.85,
        maxHeight: geometry.size.height*0.85
)
```

Form View contains:

```
 VStack(spacing: 4) {
            FormInput(label: "First Name", input: self.$firstName) {
                isEditing in

                self.avoider.editingField = 0
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .padding(0)
            .avoidKeyboard(tag: 0)
```

Comment: I don't get what you want and what you have.

Comment: I fount it. Generally I have white rectangle FormView in the center (that is set to max 85% of screen height) then I have input fields that are said to be 40pt height (they are inside VStack) FormInput has frame maxWidth/maxHeight set to .infinity. 
And it works just this .avoidKeyboard modifier that set .preference() and was using GeometryReader make this layout was breaking. I changed just order of frame() and avoidKeybaord() modifiers and it start working great again!

Comment: i'm curious about `.avoidKeyboard` modifier, can you share a link for its gist ?

Comment: https://github.com/michzio/KeyboardAvoider/blob/843284563c5453bc8af094ba7f2258f09d4c4e51/KeyboardAvoider/KeyboardAvoider/KeyboardAvoiderPreferences.swift

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason why sometimes View (layout) does not collapse to take smallest possible space, but instead expands to maxHeigh/maxWidth.

It happens when somewhere in between we use

```
GeometryReader { geometry in

    VStack { ... }

}
```

Then those Views does not collapse and spread to maxHeight. I have this GeometryReader used inside `.avoidKeyboard(tag: 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue but managed to fix it by specifying `idealHeight` instead `maxHeight` and also adding a `minHeight`. So your example would be something like:

```
FormView()
     .frame(
       maxWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.85,
       idealHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.85,
       minHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.6
)
```

On a device with enough space, the ideal height will be used, on smaller devices the height will shrink but not to less than `minHeight`.